# How to check if the imputed value from caret is reliable? (predicting missing values)

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-imputation

I have a dataset which has some missing values and I tried to predict them by using caret. My data set looks like this

```
treatment   block   D10     ni10    am10    Plot
       1    1      W1 10    0.010   0.011   S1-1
       0    2      W2 10    0.002   0.014   S0-2
       0    1      W3 10    0.019   0.012   S0-1
       2    2      W4 10    0.007   0.010   S2-2
       2    1      W5 10                    S2-1
       1    2      W6 10                    S1-2
       0    3      W7 10    0.019   0.041   S0-3
       2    4      W8 10    0.009   0.017   S2-4
       2    3      W9 10    0.028   0.014   S2-3
       1    4      W10 10   0.007   0.022   S1-4
       1    3      W11 10   0.011   0.010   S1-3
       0    4      W12 10                   S0-4
```

As you can see I have some missing data. I tried to predict the data by using caret.

```
library(caret)
library(doSNOW)
a<-data

summary(a$ni10)
a$Missingni10<- ifelse(is.na(a$ni10),"Y","N")

summary(a$am10)
a$Missingam10<- ifelse(is.na(a$am10),"Y","N")

a$Missingni10<-as.factor(a$Missingni10)
a$treatment<-as.factor(a$treatment)
a$block<-as.factor(a$block)
a$Missingam10<-as.factor(a$Missingam10)

str(a)

features<-c("treatment","block","ni10","am10","Missingni10","Missingam10")
a<-a[,features]
str(a)


dummy.vars <- dummyVars(~.,data=a[,-1])
a.dummy<-predict(dummy.vars,a[,-1])
View(a.dummy)

pre.process<- preProcess(a.dummy,method="bagImpute")
imputed.data<- predict(pre.process,a.dummy)
View(imputed.data)
```

Then I get the missing data.
How can I test if the imputed data are actually reliable?

Answer (score 1):

Imputing on missing values can be viewed as a predictive model in another layer.

- Suppose you are imputing a continuous variable, then all the metrics to evaluate continuous outcome can be used, Such as R2, RMSE, etc.
- Suppose you are imputing a discrete variable, then all the metrics to evaluate discrete outcome can be used, Such as Accuracy, False positive rate (assume binary), False negative rate, etc.

Comment: Punch out some **known** values and see how your imputations compare to the real thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the imputation inside of resampling since it is a significant part of your model workflow.

If it is doing a poor job, the resampling results should reflect that in the model performance values.